# Flutter android_alarm_manager oneShot is not working after close app

Tags: android, flutter, alarmmanager, background-process, dart-pub

I want to execute some task (e.g. fetch data from server) in background even app is closed in Flutter App.
So How can I achive this?
Its' better If anyone provide example for that.

I am trying using android_alarm_manager but facing below issue:

I have cloned ahttps://github.com/jsoref/flutter-plugins/tree/master/packages/android_alarm_manager/example

Modified code as below:

```
void printPeriodic() => printMessage("Periodic!");
void printonDelayed() async {
  int i = 0;
  while(i < 50) {
  printMessage("printonDelayed:" + i.toString());
  await sleep1();
  i++;
}
Future<String> sleep1() {
  return new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () => "1");
} 
await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
  const Duration(seconds: 1), oneShotID, printOneShot, exact: true);
await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
  const Duration(seconds: 1), 2, printonDelayed, wakeup: true, exact: true);
```

Periodic! is printing even if I close app.

**printonDelayed is not printing if I close app**

Android Version: 8.1.0